# Método para calculo de media harmônica!

Tags: c, matemática, estatística-bootstrap

Ola preciso de uma ajuda para realizar um calculo de media harmônica de uma serie "infinita" por assim dizer.
Ex. Tenho um sistema de captura de dados que esta sempre injetando informações em um BD. Porem são muitos pontos adicionados a cada minuto e eu preciso gerar um valor da media histórica de todos os pontos da serie desde seu inicio... 
Isso gera muito tempo de processamento do BD e do PC para a cada minuto ficar atualizando essa estatística...

Gostaria de saber se teria alguma forma de fazer uma consolidação da media até o ultimo minuto e depois realizar a nova média apenas com esse valor consolidado e os novos potos aquisitados após a consolidação???

Estou programando em C com BD SQLServer.

Obrigado..

Comment: Não entendi por que exatamente usar média harmônica; há obrigatoriedade nisso? Pelo que entendi, você quer calcular certa média de acordo com a amostragem feita, periodicamente. Por que não usar https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9dia_m%C3%B3vel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A média (aritmética) é calculada da seguinte forma,

```
float media = 0.0;

for (int i = 0; i < qtd; ++i)
{
    media += historico[i];
}

media /= qtd;
```

Para uma contagem `novaqtd = qtd + 1` e uma média anterior igual a `media`, a nova média `novamedia`, com a chegada de um novo valor histórico `historico[qtd]`, seria:

```
float novamedia = (qtd * media + historico[qtd]) / (qtd + 1);
```

ou seja,

```
float novamedia = (media + historico[qtd] / qtd) / (1 + (1 / qtd));
```

Algoritmo:

- Tome o novo valor histórico e divida pela contagem anterior
- Some à média anterior
- Com o valor obtido, divida por (1 + (1 / contagem anterior))
- Esta é a nova média

Note algumas coisas:

- Se a contagem for muito alta, (1 / contagem) vai ser um valor muito baixo e (1 + (1 / contagem)), um valor muito próximo de 1, o que é de se esperar, porque amostras muito grandes tendem a ter a média mais próxima da média da população
- Dada a exatidão necessária, é possível simplificar a fórmula para: `float novamedia = media + historico[qtde] / qtde;`

Comment: Acredito que vai dar certo desta forma... A quantidade de pontos esperados é de aprox. 32.000.000 e depois será zerada a amostragem novamente. Como a precisão é de apenas 03 casa decimais acredito que a tendencia é realmente ir a 1 nas novas amostragens. Mais enfim temos que fazer conforme o solicitado!. hehehe obrigado pela ajuda..